# In Minecraft, can one player's latency affect another's?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

My son plays Minecraft Java Edition. He has his own Minecraft realm on a remote server, and he is convinced that he experiences high lag and even loses his connection when a certain other player joins. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

That could happen, but it depends on each player's network environment.

If your son's (more likely your house's) internet connection is very low quality (like using Wifi at far from router, low connection speed, etc), that could happen. I suspect that's the case here, since your son's getting kicked out of server.

Or, one possibility, your son and his friend's connection to Realms server might be bad, so that causes your son's getting kicked out of server. If your son is experiencing high lag without anyone being in the Realms server, this might be the case.

Though, both possibilities can be coexist, so it'd be good to investigate what's causing the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this could absolutely happen. However, things would have to go really, really wrong on one end or the other. I doubt that your son is lying; this has happened to me when someone (who lives roughly an hour away from me) joined. It kicked us both.

Comment: This could do with more details.

Comment: yeah but i don't think it deserved all the downvotes.